# How to get Particular Json Data By Filtering Through Url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, json-api

I'm new to working with Json, **I want to get Particular Id data from Json array**.
This is the api url i'm using.

```
http://example/plapi/areas?jsoncallback=?
```

This url returning json array like

```
([{"area_id":"25","ca_id":"0","area_name":"Durgapuram","alias_area":"","area_sp‌​l":"No","area_lat":"16.52069","area_lng":"80.64067","area_desc":"","area_image":"‌​","map_image":"","area_status":"1","city_id":"27","position":"0","m_keyword":""},‌​{"area_id":"26","ca_id":"0","area_name":"Arundalpet","alias_area":"","area_spl":"‌​No","area_lat":"16.30520","area_lng":"80.44169","area_desc":"","area_image":"","m‌​ap_image":"","area_status":"1","city_id":"31","position":"0","m_keyword":""})]
```

In that I want get data only city_id=31.

To get Data having id as 31, I'm Doing like this

```
var data = {
"id": "31",
};
$.getJSON("http://example/plapi/areas?jsoncallback=?",JSON.stringify(data) ,function(result){console.log(result);
});
```

But it is returning nothing.

I want to get only 31 id associated data not others. Please help me how to do?

Comment: Is not creal what you need. you need to parse the json and extract some data or you need to fetch some specific data from the backend?

Comment: I don't think `jsoncallback` is used to define the `id` of your query.

Comment: The above url returning all areas im having, in Json Array format, but i need data only having id as 31

Comment: Your URL looks like it's an API Point for a `JSONP` resource. Either way, you'll need to post an example of your JSON object so we can tell you how to filter out by ID.

Comment: Don't put the JSON data as a comment, update your question.

Comment: id means u want  only key value right ?

Comment: want key value having 31 as city_id

Answer (score 0):

Find JS Code to Get Only `City_ID` from your `JSON`:-

```js
var jsonData = [
    {
       
        "area_id": "25",
        "ca_id": "0",
        "area_name": "Durgapuram",
        "alias_area": "",
        "area_spl": "No",
        "area_lat": "16.52069",
        "area_lng": "80.64067",
        "area_desc": "",
        "area_image": "1",
        "map_image": "",
        "area_status": "1",
         "city_id": "27",
        "position": "0",
        "m_keyword": ""
    },
   {
        
       "area_id": "26",
        "ca_id": "0",
        "area_name": "Arundalpet",
        "alias_area": "",
        "area_spl": "No",
        "area_lat": "16.30520",
        "area_lng": "80.44169",
        "area_desc": "",
        "area_image": "",
        "map_image": "",
        "area_status": "1",
       "city_id": "31",
        "position": "0",
        "m_keyword": ""
    }
];

for(var obj in jsonData){
    if(jsonData.hasOwnProperty(obj)){
    for(var prop in jsonData[obj]){
        if(jsonData[obj].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
            if(prop=="city_id"){
                prop;
                alert(prop);
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

Happy to Help

Comment: I don't want to restrict values using if condition, want to filter in url itself by passing values in `$.getJson('url', {city_id=31})` like that.